# How to update a column in a table from another column in another table

Tags: sql

Please I have a `table1` that has one of its columns named price.
And I have another `table2` that has one of its columns named price.
I want to update column price in `table2` with the value in column price in `table1`.

I tried this script but it didn't update it.

```
BEGIN 

UPDATE [WAC].[dbo].[IV00101]
   SET 
      [STNDCOST] = (Select LISTPRCE from IV00105 WHERE IV00101.ITEMNMBR = 'IV00105.ITEMNMBR')
      WHERE IV00101.ITEMNMBR = 'IV00105.ITEMNMBR'

END
```

please help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably because you have enclosed `IV00105.ITEMNMBR` in quotes.  This is causing the database engine to search for an item named "IV00105.ITEMNMBR" rather than join the two tables and pick up appropriate rows.

This will work (assuming table names based on the query you provided):

```
UPDATE [WAC].[dbo].[IV00101]
SET 
    [STNDCOST] = LISTPRCE 
From IV00105 
WHERE [WAC].[dbo].[IV00101].ITEMNMBR = IV00105.ITEMNMBR
```

Comment: Hello Raj, Thank you so much that script really resolve my problem.